# Unable to add calendar events programmatically for Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to create a button in an android app that is able to add an event to a calendar without launching an intent.

I found this official android resource which explains how to achieve this.

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
...

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I've tested this code on many devices including 2.3, 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2.

It seems like this is unable to work on 4.1 devices. I've tried to use this code to add a calendar event but to no avail. Can anyone else confirm this bug on 4.1? Or is there a workaround for adding a calendar event to 4.1?

Comment: This is the android resource that explains how to add events to the calendar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @greatergoodguy were you resolve this issue, i am facing same ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In documentation you can read:

> > In practice, inserts and updates should be done in an asynchronous thread to move the action into a background thread.

Remove the last line of your code and use this:

```
AsyncQueryHandler handler = new MyHandler(getContentResolver());
handler.startInsert(0, null, Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

where `MyHandler` is a class that extends `AsyncQueryHandler` (that is abstract):

```
public class MyHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {
    public MyHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
        super(cr);
    }
}
```

This works for me.

Other two details that could cause misunderstandings:

- In `Calendar` class the month value is 0-based
- To write calendar without intents you must put the specific permission in Manifest file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />`